# <a> tags not clicking when containing <nav> position set to fixed in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position, href, nav

I'm in the process of creating a nav bar and I got everything working properly except when I set the nav to fixed position, the links do not clink. If I delete position: fixed, the links are clickable and work properly.

Here is my html code:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#one">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Knowledge</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and CSS:

```
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I have other CSS but it is not affecting this issue.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely it's a z-index issue. Right-click on one of the links and choose "inspect". My guess is that the inspected element isn't the link you thought you'd inspected.

Comment: Are you sure? It's working good now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Utkanos. I researched the z-index and set it to 1 and now it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Here's my CSS code now:

```
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```